# returning int in ajax complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, integer

I am returing integer in Json result and then want to deal with that result.

**Returning it like -**

```
 return Json(new { data = Model.UserID });
```

**Trying to use it in ajaxComplete function-**

```
  complete: function (data) {
                var id = parseInt(data);
                window.location.url = '/Upload/Myuploads/UserID=' + id;

            }
```

But this function shows me null at the end point.

How do I deal with integer results in ajax

Answer (score 5):

The `data` that you are returning in your controller actually winds up being a property on the `data` in your javascript.

This should give you the value:

```
var id = parseInt(data.data);
```

Comment: For instance this property of id is happening on onComplete not on `success` function. My wild guess is it doesn't even know what the data is. I think there must be some difference on complete and success results of ajax. Right?

Comment: That could be another issue. I didn't catch that when I read your question. I would change to success as my preference. But open the Javascript Console (Ctrl-Shift-J) and put a breakpoint inside your complete function and take a look at your `data` object. The point still stands though that you have some confusion because you're using the same name for two different objects.

Comment: That was the reason, changed it to success as you preferred. I still can't understand for complete function. Finally, Got it working with changing `complete` to `success`.

Comment: `complete` would be for something to do regardless of success or failure. But it wouldn't have access to anything inside the scope of either the `success` or `failure` methods as it is a different method call together.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
return Json(new { data = Model.UserID });
```

You are returning one object to the success call of ajax. You can wrap multiple properties inside this object
e.g

```
  return Json(new { data = Model.UserID,Name=Model.Name,AnyProp=Model.SomeProp });
```

You should access this in success function and not in complete as complete is called even if error occurs

```
success: function (data) {
                var id = parseInt(data.data);
                var name=data.Name;
                var prop=data.AnyProp;
                window.location.url = '/Upload/Myuploads/UserID=' + id;

            }
```

Comment: Vapre, For instance this property of id is happening on onComplete not on `success` function. My wild guess is it doesn't even know what the data is.

Comment: its Varpe, and Complete will always be called after success. Test it from ur side

Comment: You are right. But I don't know why things are not happening even after following it in right way today for me.